# ReferenceError: NavigationEnd is not defined (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have a weird problem. I'm simply trying to navigate from one component to an another. I injected Router etc, but for some reason, I get an error that NavigationEnd is not defined. I tried this and that solution, but nothing works. Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Here's the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouterModule, Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import { Event, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscribe-box',
  templateUrl: './subscribe-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscribe-box.component.scss']
})
export class SubscribeBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

 ngOnInit() {

  }

  emailSubscribe(email) {

    this.router.navigate(["/subscribe-success"]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all those imports in your component file? It seems that all you nees is just `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router} from '@angular/router';` assumin that you are using http client somewhere. Also you should not import `RouterModule` in the component file but you should import it in the module, eg. `NgModule({...imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)...]}) export class SomeModule` where `...` stands for other non relevant stuff, have you included `RouterModule` that way?

Comment: Plese post your module file to show whole picture, and routing module file if you use one

Comment: All those imports are just trying to "fix" the problem, as I don't know why the simple router.navigate method can trigger an error that there's no NavigationEnd defined.

Module and routing module are simple modules with added components and routes, there's nothing special about them. I have router.navigate functions in other components, but as the part of router.subscribe, and there it works as supposed.

Note: I'm not a beginner with Angular. Bunch of imports you see at the top are just trying to see does something miss or is not properly imported in modules, but it's not the case.

Comment: I fixed it, I had some out-of-reason "subscription" method to the route in the parent component